# How to easily compare 2 lines made out of points in space?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, distance, vector-graphics, gesture-recognition

I'd like to compare ordered points in space to recognize a gesture. Iam recording users  hand position as he is moving it in space. Iam only looking to create a simple proof of concept. Seems like AI is the best way to go for the end product, but before I dwell into that, is there a good algorithm to compare two lines made of points in space? Ideally if it would give me a similarity percentage.

The issues Iam having with a naive implementation of calculating distances between each pair of points is that the points don't neceserily align. The user can start a few points early or too late and the ideal alignment is broken. Any tips?

Comment: See [Similarity measures between curves?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27861/57179). If you already have a common reference point (i.e. similar gestures are expected to be aligned), you could directly use something like the [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've looked into it but I can't even understand if it's applicable to points in 3D space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to it is just brute force. I made a regular linear comparison. Then I run it through variable array lengths (excluding the first few points if the player starts the gesture too early), only comparing up to the shortest array. After that there is a second loop of cheking the distance between rotated variations of the recorded gesture. The performance is ofcourse horrible, but through some  optimization it's quite usable. Not checking the rest of the array if it's already too far, for example. It's also very easily threadable.